# Unexpected behavior of Windows.Forms.TextBox on Clear() or simple set to string.Empty after ShowDialog() called

Tags: .net, textbox, corruption

In a form with a vanilla textbox where `multiline == false`, the expected results occur
when setting the Text property to "", or string.Empty, or calling Clear().  However once
ShowDialog() has been called on the form, the behavior outlined below occurs.  Also note that the weird effect is fairly immediate.  If there is a Load event handler defined and used, as soon as it is called (in response to ShowDialog() being invoked), the unexplained behavior shown below is true.

```
textBox.Text = "fillWithSomething";
```

debugger shows Text to be: "fillWithSomething"

```
textBox.Text = "";
```

debugger shows Text to be:  two unprintable characters with textBox.Text.Length == 2

```
textBox.Text = "fillWithNew";
```

debugger shows Text to be:  "fillWithNew"

```
textBox.Clear();
```

debugger again shows Text to be two unprintable characters with Length == 2

This is all part of a larger Form client application.   I tried a simple test
(both 3.5 & 4 .Net Framework) and same behaviors.

Any suggestions as to what might be corrupting what seems should be a really
straight-foward operation?  I find no references to this type of problem elsewhere.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but `.Length` isn't a property of a TextBox. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx Are you sure it's not an extension method or something?

Comment: Put textBox.Text.ToCharArray() in the debugger expression and tell us what you see.

Comment: I really meant  textbox.Text.Length (typo).  When TocharArray() used, the resulting array hold two characters with the values charArray[0] == 0xA808 and charArray[1] == 0x532

Answer (score 0):

I just dropped a textbox on a form, and I am not seeing the behavior you're seeing. both `=""` and `.Clear()` give set it to the empty string with length 0. There must be something else interfering.

Comment: I did the same, with the same neutral result.... was hoping the failure pattern above may be familiar to someone.  What's odd is that back-to-back assignments of a non-blank, non-empty string appears to work fine.